# Related model doesnt update value in memory after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have something like a job-hunting website. There are `Position` models and each position has many `Offers`. When one offer is accepted, the rest are rejected and the position is closed. My tests for `Offer` pass as expected, however, the tests for `Position` fail because `is_accepted` remains `nil`...

```
test "accept_offer flips is_accepted bits" do
    p = FactoryGirl.create(:position_with_offers, offers: 3)

    assert_nil e.offers[0].is_accepted # pass
    assert_nil e.offers[1].is_accepted # pass
    assert_nil e.offers[2].is_accepted # pass
    assert_equal false, p.is_closed    # pass

    p.accept_offer(e.offers[0])

    assert_equal true, p.is_closed              # pass
    assert_equal true, e.offers[0].is_accepted  # fail, == nil
    assert_equal false, e.offers[1].is_accepted # fail, == nil
    assert_equal false, e.offers[2].is_accepted # fail, == nil

end
```

...and...

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :offers, inverse_of: :position

    def accept_offer(_offer)
        offers.each do |o|
            if o.id == _offer.id
                o.accept
            else
                o.reject
            end
            o.reload
        end
        update({ is_closed: true })
    end
end
```

...and...

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
    def accept
        update_column(:is_accepted, true)
    end
    def reject
        update_column(:is_accepted, false)
    end
end
```

I've read that `.reload` should be called to refresh the model. I've put reload on everything with no success. I've tried variations of `update_all`, `update_attribute`, `update_column` but the offers are always `nil`. Interestingly, if I `puts` the values in `position.accept_offer`, the correct values are rendered.

What do I need to do to get this test to pass?

Answer (score 0):

Reload the offers.

```
assert_equal true, e.offers[0].reload.is_accepted  # fail, == nil
assert_equal false, e.offers[1].reload.is_accepted # fail, == nil
assert_equal false, e.offers[2].reload.is_accepted # fail, == nil
```